# Getting reference to the elements of a tuple

Tags: c++, reference, stl, tuples

Let's say I have a tuple containing types `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
std::tuple<A,B,C> t;
```

How can I extract a reference to one of it's elements, a mutable reference, so that I can modify it?

`std::get` returns a copy.

Comment: `std::get` does return a reference. Did you try `std::get<0>t = A{};`? The only reason you got a copy is probably because you tried assigning it to a non-reference variable.

Comment: @patatahooligan Thanks for helping, can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to what you said in the OP, `std::get` returns a reference. In fact it even has an overload for `tuple&&` that returns a `T&&`. Your misunderstanding probably stems from the fact that you were using it in an expression that results in a copy. A notable example of this would be `auto` which is designed to not declare a reference by default. Take a look at the following code.

```
std::tuple<int, int> my_tuple;

// Declare an int whose value is copied from the first member of the tuple
auto my_int = get<0>(my_tuple);

// Get a reference to it instead
auto& my_int_ref = std::get<0>(my_tuple);
my_int_ref = 0;    // Assign 0 to the first element

// Direct use inside an expression also works.
std::get<0>(my_tuple) = 1;    // Assign 1 to the first element.
```